# How to ensure requests to my servers functions only by a single origin / UI?

Tags: node.js, express, user-interface, authentication, server

I have a node.js server that has HTTP CRUD functions to my mongoDB.

And an Android application that sends requests though those functions.

I would like to ensure that my server will answer requests from specific origins.

For example: only answer requests from the android app, or my pc postman's requests.

How can I ensure that no one else sending requests using the same urls and ports will get answered?

This is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var db = require('./config/db');
var app = express();


const port = 8000;
app.use(bodyParser.json());



MongoClient.connect(db.url, (err, database) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)


    db = database.db("getremp")
    require('./app/routes')(app, db);



        app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => {

            console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode - We Are lIVE!",app.settings.env.port, app.settings.env);
    });

})
```

and my index.js:

```
const noteRoutes = require('./note_routes');
module.exports = function (app, db) {
    noteRoutes(app, db);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control this with :

- Send a specific header with your datas containing a secret key, then control the header in your node app [How to check headers in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409154/how-to-check-headers-in-nodejs)
- Use HMAC in order to authenticate the user and control the integrity of datas : [Node Hmac Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892167/node-hmac-authentication/39897002#39897002)

But you've to remember that all traffic going out from an mobile app can be intercept (with Fiddler for example). Never use a static (non-dynamic) value to ensure authentication

Comment: Will I need to change every function on my server and every function on my app to check / send the header?

Comment: with header you will simply need to register a new middleware in your express app, in your app you will need to add a header on each call of your api

Comment: I don't  really understand where and how exactly I can use this on server-side once.. by the example you sent I can see that it uses req.headers ... this you get inside the api functions..

Comment: Sorry.. i'm still learning Node.js.. I've seen that I can just add a middleware using those functions. Like seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094417/authenticating-the-request-header-with-express   
Thank you very much!